# Impressora zebra + PHP + Linux

Tags: php

Estou gerando um arquivo em PHP com os comandos em ZPL e enviando para a impressora via comando do linux `lpr -P`, o problema é que na impressora está sendo impresso os comandos que estão no arquivo e não a etiqueta formatada.
Alguém tem idéia do que pode estar ocorrendo?

Segue código usado!

```php
$lc_nome = 'rel_etiqueta.prn';
$lc_handle = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/' . $lc_nome, 'w+');

/*
if(empty({etiquetas_por_item})||{etiquetas_por_item==0})
{
  {etiquetas_por_item} = 1;
}
*/

//var_dump([total_selecionados]);

for($x=0;$x<$tot;$x++)
{

  $linha  = explode('#', [total_selecionados][$x]);

  fputs($lc_handle,'^XA');
  fputs($lc_handle,'^MMT');
  fputs($lc_handle,'^PW831');  
  fputs($lc_handle,'^LL0240');  
  fputs($lc_handle,'^LS0 ');  
  fputs($lc_handle,'^FX  Produto Coluna 1');
   
  $nome_item    = '^FT40,60^A0N,40,30^FD'.  $linha[0] .'^FS';
  fputs($lc_handle,$nome_item);

  $codigo_item  = '^FO40,80^BC^FD'       .  $linha[1] .'^FS';
  fputs($lc_handle,$codigo_item);
  
  fputs($lc_handle,'^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ');
  fputs($lc_handle,'^XA^ID000.GRF^FS^XZ');
  fputs($lc_handle,'^XA^ID001.GRF^FS^XZ');
  
}
        
fclose($lc_handle);

echo '</br>===== ' .  $itens . ' ===== </br>';

//$arquivo = '<a href="/tmp/rel_etiqueta.prn" target="_blank">abrir</a>';
$lc_arquivo = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/tmp/' . $lc_nome;
//$command = "lpr -P " . {IMPRESSORA} . " " . $lc_arquivo;
$command = "lpr -P " . 'zebra' . " " . $lc_arquivo;

//var_dump($comando);


exec($command);
```

Comment: Qual o comando inteiro chamado pelo PHP?

Comment: bom dia Jefferson, editei meu post com o código que estou usando!